# Cannot figure out why submit button is not working

Tags: javascript, html

The submit button seems to not be running the code from what I can tell, but I'm not sure if that is what is wrong with the code. Spent a long time trying to figure it out, but still have no idea. The forms and everything seem to be right, but when I click submit the only thing that happens is that the form entries disappear and the button seems to just reset the form. In html testers it says that the file is not found so I have no clue on what I should do to debug this particular issue.

```
<html>
    <title>Assignment 5</title>
    <body>
    <form>
        <h2>Step 1: Enter your name, address, etc.</h2>
        <formid="Computerparts">
         First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
         Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
         City: <input type="text" name="city"> State: <input type ="text" name="state"> Zip: <input type="text" name="zipcode"><br>
         Phone: <input type="text" name="phonenumber"><br>
         Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>

<h2>Step 2: Select the computer components you want</h2>

    CPU: <input type="radio" name="cpu"> Intel 2.0 GHz <input type="radio" name="cpu"> Intel 2.2 GHz <input type="radio" name="cpu"> Intel 3.0 GHz<br>

        RAM: <input type="radio" name="ram">SIMM 1 GB <input type="radio" name="ram">SIMM 2 GB <input type="radio" name="ram" value="75">SIMM 4 GB<br>

        HDD: <input type="radio" name="hdd"> IDE 60 GB<input type="radio" name="hdd"> IDE 120 GB<input type="radio" name="hdd"> IDE 250 GB<br>
    <h2>Step 3: Select the optional Software you want</h2>
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" name="software" value="25">Adobe Creative Suite 4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="software">Microsoft Office 2007<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="software">Symantec Antivirus 2010<br>
<input type="submit" value = "submit" onclick="doSubmit()" /><button type="reset" value="Reset">Clear Entries</button>
</form>

    <script>

    function doSubmit(){

    formTest = document.getElementById("Computerparts");


    if(formTest.fname.value == ""){
        alert("Name can not be empty");
        formTest.name.focus();
        return;
    }


    if(formTest.city.value  == ""){
        alert("City can not be empty");
        formTest.city.focus();
        return;
    }

    if(formTest.state.value.length != 2){
        alert("state must be 2 letters");
        formTest.state.focus();
        return;
    }

    if(formTest.zip.value.length != 5){
        alert("zip must be 5 digits");
        formTest.zip.focus();
        return;
    }

    if(formTest.phone.value  == ""){
        alert("Phone can not be empty");
        formTest.phone.focus();
        return;
    }

    if(formTest.email.value == ""){
        alert("Email can not be empty");
        formTest.email.focus();
        return;
    }
    if(formTest.lname.value == ""){
        alert("Last name can not be empty");
        formTest.lnamel.focus();
        return;
    }


    var checkcpu = false;

    for(var i=0; i<formTest.cpu.length; i++){
        if(formTest.cpu[i].checked)
            checkcpu = true;
    }

    if(checkcpu == false){
        alert("Must Choose CPU");
        return;

    }
        var pricecpu = 0;

    if(formTest.cpu[0].checked)
        price = 100;
    else if(formTest.cpu[1].checked)
        price = 120;
    else if(formTest.cpu[2].checked)
        price = 150;

var checkram = false;

    for(var i=0; i<formTest.ram.length; i++){
        if(formTest.ram[i].checked)
            checkram = true;
    }

    if(checkram == false){
        alert("Must Choose RAM!");
        return;

    }
        var priceram = 0;

    if(formTest.ram[0].checked)
        price = 25;
    else if(formTest.ram[1].checked)
        price = 50;
    else if(formTest.ram[2].checked)
        price = 75;


var checkhdd = false;

    for(var i=0; i<formTest.hdd.length; i++){
        if(formTest.hdd[i].checked)
            checkhdd = true;
    }

    if(checkhdd == false){
        alert("Must Choose HDD!");
        return;

    }


    var pricehdd = 0;

    if(formTest.hdd[0].checked)
        price = 60;
    else if(formTest.hdd[1].checked)
        price = 100;
    else if(formTest.hdd[2].checked)
        price = 200;


    for(var i=0; i<formTest.software.length; i++){
        if(formTest.software[i].checked)
            price += 25;
    }
    var price = pricehdd + priceram + pricecpu

    alert("Order Submitted , Total: " + price);

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to validate a form is to use the form's submit event and return false if error, true if ok = also where is your action? If no action the page will be submitted to itself:

```
<form id="computerparts" onsubmit="return doSubmit(this)" action="???">
```

remove the invalid tag formid and the `onclick="doSubmit()"` from the submit button and use

```
function doSubmit(formTest) {
   // formTest = document.getElementById("Computerparts"); remove this

  if(formTest.fname.value == ""){
    alert("Name can not be empty");
    formTest.name.focus();
    return false; // return false when error
  }
  .
  .
  .
  return true; // allow submit
}
```